# Artillery.io how send headers

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I need to send headers to the server before testing socket.io. How can i do this?

I try, but the header I want is not sent to the server

[Scenario](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pbezpal/88dded6b98bf02e29d311b5d0153defe/raw/2011482b22975d2f487847dfd895e2c9b899cdd8/sxenario)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can set your headers in default parameter inside config like this:

```
config:
    target: "http://localhost:3000"
    phases:
        - duration: 10
          arrivalRate: 100
    defaults:
        headers:
            authorization: token
            ...
scenarios:
...
```

Comment: Thank you. How to send user-agent in headers?

Answer (score 1):

You can also send for individual requests, like:

```
      - post:
          url: '/graphql'
          headers:
            Authorization: 'Bearer {{ token }}'
          json:
            query: |
              {
                currentUser {
                  id
                  token
                }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation: https://artillery.io/docs/guides/guides/test-script-reference.html

```
config:
  target: https://my.microservice.internal
  phases:
    - duration: 600
      arrivalRate: 10
  defaults:
    headers:
      x-api-key: "xyz"
scenarios:
  - flow:
      - get:
          url: "/"
```